# '.htaccess' file Disappeared after i upload it to ftp on alwaysdata.com 

Tags: python, django, hosting

I follow this article : [deploying-django-at-alwaysdata-com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955189/deploying-django-at-alwaysdata-com)

and i'm not successful now , look my site : http://zjm1126.alwaysdata.net/:

[image]

i think it is due to the `'.htaccess'` file , so i create it using nano , and update it using ftp tools :

[image]

but, when i upload `'.htaccess'` file to the `ftp.alwaysdata.com` , the  `'.htaccess'` file  Disappeared,

Is is the reason i cant show the my page,

thanks

Comment: Keep in mind that starting filenames with "." is a convention used to indicate the file is hidden. Many programs (like `ls` for example) don't display these files by default.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that your FTP client is willing to show files of unknown (or hidden as the . specifies) extensions. After that you will need to create or edit the .htaccess file on your site to ensure that privileges exist for users to read the files in question.

As always, I prefer to provide tutorials rather than a 10 second "how-to" that misses the point, so here's one I've always liked

http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess.shtml

If you need more specifics to your situation, please provide additional details and I'll do my best to provide an example.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal: A leading dot  marks hidden files on Unix/Linux systems.

The file is hidden from your FTP client, but it is still there.

FTP clients like FileZilla can make it visible anyway (I think by probing actively for that file name).